# Postgresql json like query

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have the following table called module_data.  Currently it has three rows of entries:

```
                id                               data
0ab5203b-9157-4934-8aba-1512afb0abd0 {"title":"Board of Supervisors Meeting","id":"1i3Ytw1mw98"}
7ee33a18-63da-4432-8967-bde5a44347a0 {"title":"Board of Supervisors Meeting","id":"4-dNAg2mn6o"}
8d71ca35-74eb-4751-b635-114bf04843f1 {"title":"COPD 101", "id":"l9O0jCR-sxg"}
```

Column data's datatype is `jsonb`.  I'm trying to query it using `like` operator. Something like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM module_data WHERE title LIKE '%Board%';
```

I've been looking at the `jsonb` support and there doesn't seem to be a `like` operator. If anyone has any advice.

Comment: The `like` operator exists, but a `title` column does not. It is a *property/attribute* of the `data` column, thus [you'll need to extract it's value](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) to compare it: `data ->> 'title'` or `data #>> ARRAY['title']`

Answer (score 165, accepted):

If the data column is text type, then use `->>` on cast:

```
select * from module_data where data::json->>'title' like '%Board%'
```

If it's already json:

```
select * from module_data where data->>'title' like '%Board%'
```

Comment: Awesome,  Thank you.  Its my first time using jsonb so I really appreciate the tip

Comment: Reminder to those who reading the answer: Use query parameter to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: @baijum what is query parameter?

Answer (score 98):

I found the following is more straight-forward and easier for jsonb type of columns:

```
select * from table_name
where 
column_name::text like '%Something%'
```

Found a good article on more examples and implementations:
https://www.compose.com/articles/faster-operations-with-the-jsonb-data-type-in-postgresql/

Hope it helps!

Comment: This will also search keys, so be careful using this. Only use this if you can guarantee that keys won't have search term.

Comment: If you want to search on the values only and not on the keys, you can try something like

select * from table_name
where 
array_to_string( array(select value from jsonb_each_text(
)), ' ')  like '%Something%'

Comment: so much better for quick debugging

Answer (score 18):

One other option which may be sufficient for other people who've found this page is to just cast the column to text type. Eg

```
select * from module_data where data::text like '%Board%'
```

Note though, this will search over the entire json and should only be used if you can guarantee the other fields won't be a problem.

Comment: This will also search keys, so be careful using this. Only use this if you can guarantee that keys won't have search term.

Comment: I needed to search keys so perfect for me :)

Comment: This is so good for one-off searches. +1

Answer (score 1):

I Think it should be like

```
select * from module_data where data->>'$."title"' like '%Board%'
```

then only it worked for me.

Comment: `$."title"` is a really weird property name. The object property in the OP's data is just `title`.