# How can I modify my TypeORM query to also include relations passed in as a parameter?

Tags: node.js, json, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

### Context

I want to add role based authentication to a method in the UserService class of my API that restricts access to the endpoint by getting the entries of a column in my database that contains a JSON string in three possible formats for different user scopes (Note that scope is analagous to permission groups)

#### Different Scope Types that are involved

##### GLOBAL

If a user has scope type set to ***GLOBAL*** than they would have a scope value record set to an empty object, like the following:

```
{}
```

Furthermore, if *a user has is scoped to the entire system / all data*. This scope is analogous to a superuser, admin, root user, etc.

##### ORGANIZATIONS

If a user has a scope type set to ***ORGANIZATION*** than that user can only access resources for users that are also within the same organization as them. Meaning ***the user has access to all resources that are associated to one or more organizations.***.

The value for the scope value column in the db would look something like this:

```json
{
    "organizations": [
        {"id": "1"},
        {"id": "2"}
    ]
}
```

If a user had the aforementioned scope value, and their scope type was set to ***ORGANIZATION*** than that means that they have permissions to access all resources for ***STORES*** and users who have organizationid of 1 or an organizationid of 2.

##### STORES

If a user has a scope type set to ***STORE*** than that user can only access resources for if they are part of the organization that the stores exist within.  Meaning that if a user has a scope type of ***STORE*** and they are part of an organization with id 3 and try to access a store with a organization of id 2 they can't access that resource.  A user has access to resources associated one or more stores within one or more organizations. In practice, a store scoped user will only be scoped to stores within one organization.

The scope value for a user with ***STORE*** scope would look like this:

```
{
    "organizations": [{
        "id":1,
        "stores": [
            {"id": 3},
            {"id":4}
        ]
    }]
}
```

#### Putting it all together (examples)

**Organization A Scope Value Example**

```json
// Organization A
{
    "organizations": [
        {"id": "1"},
        {"id": "2"}
    ]
}
```

**Store  A Scope Value Example**

```json
// Store A
{
    "organizations": [{
        "id":1,
        "stores": [
            {"id": 1},
            {"id": 2}
        ]
    }]
}
```

**Organization B Scope Value Example**

```
// Organization B
{
    "organizations": [
        {"id": "3"},
        {"id": "4"}
    ]
}
```

**Store B Scope Value Example**

```json
// Store B
{
    "organizations": [{
        "id": 4,
        "stores": [
            {"id": 3},
            {"id":4}
        ]
    }]
}
```

Using the above examples Organization A should be able to access resources for Store A since Organization B has id's 1 and 2 but Organization A shouldn't be able to access any resources in Store B since store B is scoped to Organization B and thus Store B is not part of Organization A

### Problem

The problem I am running into is I can't figure out how to write the Query using a query builder in TypeORM. I am able to get it half way working when writing raw SQL and using the **.query() method** but this is less than ideal. I want to be able to return the same data that I was returning when using the **getRepository() method**. But also adding the role based permissions into the query. One problem I have run into that necessitates the need for the QueryBuilder class is that is the only way to check if the user making the request to the endpoint has a scope value that is a subset of the user they are attempting to request resources for, the scope value is stored as a string in the db table as well.

Furthermore, I need to be able to pass in the resources I want to also retrieve with the query using a method parameter.

The previous query looks like this:

```
export class UserService {

  public async getUser(
    userContext: UserContext,
    organizationId: string,
    userId: string,
    shallow?: boolean,
  ): Promise<User | null> {
    if (!process.env.USER_API_DISABLE_SECURITY && userContext && userContext.userId == userId) {
      throw new HttpError(403);
    }

    let userRelations: string[] = [];
    if (!shallow) {
      userRelations = [
        'organization',
        'organization.organizationmodules',
        'organization.organizationmodules.module',
        'userscoperoles',
        'userscoperoles.scope',
        'userscoperoles.scope.scopetype',
        'userscoperoles.role',
        'userscoperoles.role.rolepermissions',
        'userscoperoles.role.rolepermissions.permission',
      ];
    }

    const userFilter = {
      organizationid: organizationId,
      idpid: userId,
      deleted: false,
    };

    const users: [User[], number] = await this.getUsersFromDB(userRelations, userFilter, 1, 0, 'username', 'ASC');

    if (users[1] === 0) {
      return null;
    }
    return users[0][0];
  }

  private async getUsersFromDB(
    relations: string[],
    filter: any,
    page: number,
    pageSize: number,
    sortBy: string,
    sortDirection: string,
    search?: string
    ): Promise<any> {
    try {
      await dbConnectionManager.connect();

      const searchString = search ? search.substring(0, 20) : '';

      const whereClaus: string[] = [];
      searchString.split(/[ ]/g).map((searchElement) => {
        whereClaus.push({ ...filter, username: ILike(`%${searchElement}%`) });
        whereClaus.push({ ...filter, firstname: ILike(`%${searchElement}%`) });
        whereClaus.push({ ...filter, lastname: ILike(`%${searchElement}%`) });
        whereClaus.push({ ...filter, adminemail: ILike(`%${searchElement}%`) });
      });
      const usersAndCount: [User[], number] = await getRepository(
        User,
        dbConnectionManager.getConnectionName(),
      ).findAndCount({
        where: [...whereClaus],
        relations: relations,
        take: pageSize,
        skip: pageSize * (page - 1),
        order: { [sortBy]: sortDirection },
      });

      return usersAndCount;
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.code == '22P02')
        throw new HttpError(404);
      else throw error;
    }
}}
```

An example of this being implemented would be:

```
await this.userService.getUsers(
    new UserContext(req), // req is the Express request object
    "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002", // 
    1,
    5,
    username,
    "DESC",
    "Chr",
);
```

This currently returns a response similar to the following:

```json
{
  "metadata": {
    "totalcount": {
      "userid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000012",
      "organizationid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002",
      "idpid": "346b4cd7-316b-4b2b-bd73-b47629751fa4",
      "username": "ChristineJones123",
      "firstname": "Christine",
      "lastname": "Jone",
      "adminemail": "christine.jones@email.com",
      "created": "2023-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "createdby": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "lastupdated": "2023-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "lastupdatedby": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "deleted": false,
      "scopeid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000012",
      "roleid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002",
      "scopetypeid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002",
      "name": "ORGANIZATION",
      "description": "lorem ipsum dolar",
      "value": "{\"organizations\":[{\"id\":1,\"stores\":[{\"id\":3},{\"id\":4}]}]}"
    }
  }
}
```

### What I've tried

This is the most simplified version of my code that I've been able to get, which still produces the problem I described above.

So far this is what I have, this doesn't work though since it returns only the user with the hardcoded values passed to the query from the two variables *calleripdid* and *targetipdid*

````
private async getUsersFromDB(
    relations: string[],
    filter: any,
    page: number,
    pageSize: number,
    sortBy: string,
    sortDirection: string,
    search?: string,
  ): Promise<any> {
    try {
      await dbConnectionManager.connect();

      /**
       * Creates a where clause for the given search string.
       * @param {string} search - the search string to create a where clause for.
       * @returns None
       */
      const searchString = search ? search.substring(0, 20) : '';

      const whereClaus: string[] = [];

      searchString.split(/[ ]/g).map((searchElement) => {
        whereClaus.push({ ...filter, username: ILike(`%${searchElement}%`) });
        whereClaus.push({ ...filter, firstname: ILike(`%${searchElement}%`) });
        whereClaus.push({ ...filter, lastname: ILike(`%${searchElement}%`) });
        whereClaus.push({ ...filter, adminemail: ILike(`%${searchElement}%`) });
      });

      const calleripdid = '346b4cd7-316b-4b2b-bd73-b47629751fa4';
      const targetipdid = 'ba0c58be-41d8-45a5-839a-b2c7a969ee0f';
      
      const permissions = '{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001,00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002}';
      
      const subquery: SelectQueryBuilder<UserScopeRole> = await getConnection(dbConnectionManager.getConnectionName())
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .select('callerscope.value')
        .from(UserScopeRole, 'callerusr')
        .innerJoin(User, 'calleruser', 'calleruser.userid = callerusr.userid')
        .innerJoin(Scope, 'callerscope', 'callerscope.scopeid = callerusr.scopeid')
        .innerJoin(Role, 'callerrole', 'callerrole.roleid = callerusr.roleid')
        .innerJoin(RolePermission, 'callerrp', 'callerrp.roleid = callerrole.roleid')
        .innerJoin(Permission, 'callerpermission', 'callerpermission.permissionid = callerrp.permissionid')
        .where('calleruser.idpid = :calleripdid')
        // .andWhere(`callerpermission.permissionid = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001'::uuid`)
        // .orWhere(`callerpermission.permissionid = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002'::uuid`)
        .andWhere(
          `callerpermission.permissionid = ANY('{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001,00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002}')`,
        )
        .setParameter('calleripdid', calleripdid)
        .setParameter('permissions', permissions);

      const usersAndCount: SelectQueryBuilder<User> | [User[], number] | Promise<any[]> | any[] = await getConnection(
        dbConnectionManager.getConnectionName(),
      )
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .select('*')
        .from(User, 'targetuser')
        .innerJoin(UserScopeRole, 'targetuserscoperole', 'targetuserscoperole.userid = targetuser.userid')
        .innerJoin(Scope, 'targetscope', 'targetscope.scopeid = targetuserscoperole.scopeid')
        .where(
          new Brackets((qb) => {
            qb.where('targetuser.idpid = :calleripdid').orWhere(
              `targetscope.value::jsonb @> (${subquery.getQuery()})::jsonb`,
            );
            if (targetipdid) {
              qb.andWhere('targetuser.idpid = :targetipdid', { targetipdid });
            }
          }),
        )
        .setParameters({
          calleripdid,
          permissions,
          targetipdid,
        })
        .skip(pageSize * (page - 1))
        .take(pageSize)
        .getRawMany();

      return usersAndCount;
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.code == '22P02')
        // Invalid syntax for parameter value, e.g. user ID UUID.
        // Could consider this to be a general 400 (bad request) instead.
        throw new HttpError(404);
      else throw error;
    }
  }```

I have also tried writing the query like this:
```JSON
    let calleripdid = '346b4cd7-316b-4b2b-bd73-b47629751fa4';
      let targetipdid = 'ffdd167f-f007-49e6-81f2-2a66f89bc2a3';
      const usersAndCount: SelectQueryBuilder<User> | [User[], number] = getConnection()
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .select('targetuser.*')
        .addSelect('COUNT(*) OVER()', 'count')
        .from(User, 'targetuser')
        .innerJoin(UserScopeRole, 'targetuserscoperole', 'targetuserscoperole.userid = targetuser.userid')
        .innerJoin(Scope, 'targetscope', 'targetscope.scopeid = targetuserscoperole.scopeid')
        .setParameters({
          calleripdid,
        })
        .where(
          new Brackets((qb) => {
            qb.where('targetuser.idpid = :calleripdid').orWhere(
              `targetscope.value @> (
                    SELECT callerscope.value
                    FROM userscoperole callerusr
                    JOIN "user" calleruser ON calleruser.userid = callerusr.userid
                    JOIN "scope" callerscope ON callerscope.scopeid = callerusr.scopeid
                    JOIN "role" callerrole ON callerrole.roleid = callerusr.roleid
                    JOIN rolepermission callerrp ON callerrp.roleid = callerrole.roleid
                    JOIN "permission" callerpermission ON callerpermission.permissionid = callerrp.permissionid
                    WHERE calleruser.idpid = :calleripdid
                    AND callerpermission.permissionid IN ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001','00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002')
                )`,
            );
            if (targetipdid) {
              qb.andWhere('targetuser.idpid = :targetipdid', { targetipdid });
            }
          }),
        )
        .orderBy(sortDirection)
        .skip(pageSize * (page - 1))
        .take(pageSize);
````

But rewrote it since that method had errors namely due to how TypeORM parses JSON

Basically, what the code is doing is getting all the data for a specific user in this case that user is hard coded, but it should be passed as a parameter. It is retrieving the values from the different tables in the database and returning the results.

Furthermore, I also tried this approach which works to limit the access of resources but I would rather avoid writing the query in this way, it also lacks the ability to also retrieve the resources passed in via the *relations* parameter

````
   const usersAndCount: [User[], number] | any = await getManager(dbConnectionManager.getConnectionName()).query(
        `SELECT *
        FROM "user".user targetuser
        JOIN "user".userscoperole targetuserscoperole ON targetuserscoperole.userid = targetuser.userid
        JOIN "user"."scope" targetscope ON targetscope.scopeid = targetuserscoperole.scopeid
        WHERE (targetuser.idpid = :targetipdid
        OR targetscope.value::jsonb @>
        (SELECT callerscope.value
            FROM  "user".userscoperole callerusr
            JOIN  "user".user calleruser ON calleruser.userid = callerusr.userid
            JOIN  "user".scope callerscope ON callerscope.scopeid = callerusr.scopeid
            JOIN  "user".role callerrole ON callerrole.roleid = callerusr.roleid
            JOIN  "user".rolepermission callerrp ON callerrp.roleid = callerrole.roleid
            JOIN  "user".permission callerpermission ON callerpermission.permissionid = callerrp.permissionid
            WHERE calleruser.idpid = :calleripdid
            AND callerpermission.permissionid
        IN ('{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001,00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002}'))::jsonb
        )
        AND targetuser.idpid = :targetipdid
        ORDER BY targetuser.username
        OFFSET :offset
        LIMIT :limit`,
        [(offset = pageSize * (page - 1)), (limit = pageSize), targetipdid, calleripdid],
      );```

To summarize it all, I want to return the same results that this query does:
```TypeScript
  const usersAndCount: [User[], number] = await getRepository(
    User,
    dbConnectionManager.getConnectionName(),
    ).findAndCount({
        where: [...whereClaus],
        relations: relations,
        take: pageSize,
        skip: pageSize * (page - 1),
        order: { [sortBy]: sortDirection },
      });
````

But I can't figure out how to add in the logic that the above query is performing with the *whereClaus* as well as the *relations* by getting all the values passed in via the relations parameter and applying the filter done by the *whereClaus*.

### My Research

This [article](https://www.kindacode.com/article/how-to-use-subqueries-in-typeorm/) mentioned using subqueries and since that is cleaner I decided to use subqueries.

[This Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60369593/querying-a-json-field-in-typeorm)  asks a similar question but is unanswered, it did have a comment referring to this [This Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42918348/postgresql-json-like-query) but the answers there seemed to be more specific to how to do json operations in Postgres.

[This medium article](https://rahulthinking9.medium.com/how-to-query-jsonb-using-typeorm-and-postgresql-37ff7f1a3ea1) mentioned using something like this as a possible solution for getting from the jsonb column `targetscope.value::jsonb @> \'{"organizations":[{"id":1,"stores":[{"id":3},{"id":4}]}]}\'` but I  in  in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52808304/typeorm-postgresql-select-where-json-field-equals-some-value)  there was a comment mentioning SQL injection and needing to sanitize queries using this method so I am trying to avoid this approach.

This [PR on the TypeORM GitHub](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/pull/9665) mentioned that the `JsonContains` operator doesn't work, and I can confirm it doesn't work for my uses.

[This open issue in the TypeORM github repo](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2256) suggests that the only way to perform the json operations I need to with TypeORM seems to be using the *QueryBuilder* method.

[This article](https://schinckel.net/2014/05/25/querying-json-in-postgres/) mentioned that the `@>` operator is the json *subset of* operator so I presume this is what I need.

[The documentation for Postgres JSON functions here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-json.html) mentioned that the `@>` operator only gets the values for top level keys, so I am not sure if this is the best approach.

### Question

So my basic question is, how do I modify the TypeORM query I currently have in such a way that I can retrieve the results from the tables and columns passed in via the *relations* array as a parameter and restrict retrieval access of those results to only users that have the correct scope.