# json object query in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working with a row that contains JSON data. the column is like this,

```
log 
[{{"status":"orderderd","date":"2021-10-13T16:30:57.134Z"},{"status":"deivered","date":"2021-10-13T16:30:57.134Z"}}]
```

now I want to get the time when the status is delivered. How can I write a query for this?

Comment: That is not a valid JSON object.

Comment: Your first `'{'` and last `'}'`  must be `'['` and `']'`, if that is an array. In addition,  you could start trying to search in previous answers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42918348/postgresql-json-like-query

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Postgres 12 or later, you can do this quite easily using a JSON path query:

```
select jsonb_path_query_first(log, '$[*] ? (@.status == "delivered").date') #>> '{}' as delivery_date
from the_table;
```

`jsonb_path_query_first` returns a `jsonb` value and the expression `#>> '{}'` turns that into a text value.

If you are using an older version, you need to unnest the array:

```
select (select l.element ->> 'date'
        from jsonb_array_elements(t.log) as l(element)
        where l.element ->> 'status' = 'delivered'
        limit 1) as delivery_date
from the_table t;
```

Both queries assume that the column is defined as `jsonb` (which it should be). If it's not you need to cast it (e.g. `log::jsonb`)